# How to run CakePHP 2.x plugin test case from the console?

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I have created a model test case in a plugin.

Plugin name: Filters and Model name: Filter

The test Runs fine on the web runner. How do I run it in console?

I tried:

cake test Filters Case Model Filter

cake test Filters Case/Model/Filter

cake test Filters Case.Model.Filter

and about any other combination I can think of. 
Also tried same with the new testcase instead of test shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

cake testsuite PluginName Model/Filter